# More clean way to write trigger log on INSERT MySQL

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I am writing a trigger. The goal is to log the insertion in a table name `log` :

```
CREATE TABLE log (
    id int PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    column TINYTEXT,
    value MEDIUMTEXT,
);
```

My database is filled with several tables, like client. I wrote a trigger to log the client data like following:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`%` TRIGGER `client_after_insert` AFTER INSERT ON `t_client` FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLE FOR NOT FOUND SET done = TRUE;

    INSERT INTO log(column, value) VALUES
    ('name', NEW.name),
    ('surname', NEW.surname),
    ('email', NEW.email);
    # etc...
END
```

**Question**

Is there a reliable way to loop through each column in a cursor, get the colName in a 
`FETCH colCur INTO colName` and `get NEW.[colName]` ?

The goal would be to automatically fetch new value `FOR EACH COLUMNS`. This way, if we change the name of a column, we do not have to change it also in the trigger.

Comment: I think you don't have any Problem with your logic so far. Trigger execute once at a time. It is just depends on your execution flow, you can put a Stored procedure inside of it if you wanted. To much possible cases.

Comment: No, not without substantive used of prepared statements. You pretty much have dynamically create the insert statements using information_schema.columns view.